# want to create a call now button for my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, mobile

I a not a super coder, but willing to learn as well.
What I am trying to do is create the same function as : http://callnowbutton.com/ (this is a wordpress plugin) and we do NOT use wordpress.

So how would I go about creating this ? The main items are: of course only needs to show on a mobile device, and you want the button to stay at bottom of device screen, even if page is scrolled.

(so a persons thumb or finger can always access it)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I won't go about building the button for you, but once you have a button that scrolls with the page, add `<a href="tel:+1800229933">Your message!</a>` to it. On mobiles, this will start a call, whereas on tablets it will ask to add to contacts, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you.. I was familer enough with html to understand that part.. I was looking for more of the guts. (sorry I was not clear enough) but thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply put your number to call in the `href` attribute of your `a` element and precede it with 'tel:`as a protocol indicator. If you want to make it stick to the bottom of your page, use the`fixed` position CSS style. For example:

```
<style>
a.phoneMe {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<a href="tel:1234567890" class="phoneMe">Call Now!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I played around with it, and got it to work 99.9% of the way I needed it too..   I have to research css a bit more, as I want to have a logo of a PHONE, on the green background, but when I try to use background = , it wont show it correctly.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to simply add an `<img>` element inside your `<a>` element (before your text) that will point to your phone image. However, you could do it with the `:before` pseudo in CSS. Let me know if you would like me to show you an example of that.